# Data set for Software reliability prediction

Tags: testing, dataset, reliability

I am looking for Data set for Software reliability prediction.... with Failure/ Defect count.

Can any one suggest any data set with link???

Comment: Not a programming question, you could easily get this on the internet. just google/bing it....

Comment: opinionated. and you can easily find the data in the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most reliable and widespread sources for failure/defect information is a bug database. It lists all the bugs during the cycle of software development. Look at any open source software systems like eclipse. You will get a ton of information at Bugzilla and other such bug-tracking systems.

You can you this dataset - [Bug prediction dataset](http://bug.inf.usi.ch/). But to get the latest information, look at a standard bug tracker systems